# Int to format %.2f returns unexpected number on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I'm passing 0 as an argument to `String(format: "%.2f")`, it works on iPhone 5s, se, 6, 6s etc as expected ... However, it stopped working on iPhone 5, I guessed that it was a problem of 32 bit and 64 bit systems, because `%f` formats 64-bit floating-point number. Wrapped 0 with `Double(0)` and it worked, result was 0.00.

Can someone explain it in more details ?

Answer (score 2):

`String(format:)` uses the same conversion specifications as 
[`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) 
(with some additions like `%@` for objects). In particular, the `%f`
conversion expects a `Double` on the argument list, and passing 
*anything else* causes undefined behaviour: It may produce unexpected
output or crash.

On a 64-bit platform, passing `0` may work *by chance* because then
`Int` is a 64-bit integer and thus has the same size as a `Double`.
But even that is not guaranteed to work:
passing an integer argument instead of the expected floating 
pointer number is still undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use swift inbuilt method for a more consistent behavior

```
// Round the given value to a specified number
// of decimal places
func round(_ value: Double, toDecimalPlaces places: Int) -> Double {
   let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
   return round(value * divisor) / divisor
}
```

Example:

round(52.3761, toDecimalPlaces: 3) // 52.376

round(52.3761, toDecimalPlaces: 2) // 52.38